# Intellij remote tomcat print to console

Tags: intellij-idea, console, tomcat7

I'm learning java webdevelopment and I'm using tomcat 7. I set everything up so that I can remotely debug (breakspoints seem to work) my deployment on a remote tomcat server using IntelliJ.
My book on webdevelopment states that I can use `System.out.println()` in most IDE's to print to the console.
But in IntelliJ nothing shows up in the console...

Does IntelliJ support printing to the console from a remote server?
And if it does, hoe do I set it up?
Or are there any alternatives to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 solutions for my problem:
1) Use the intellij local run configuration
2) Instead of System.out.println() use log() to write to the catalina log file.